# Gridview Rows count issue

Tags: asp.net, gridview, aspxgridview

I have a page in which I have a `GridView` which contains 300 rows and 2 header row one created using template field and another created using `GridView` data bound now when I use:

```
foreach (GridViewRow GvRow in GridView1.Rows)
```

To find controls it start with 0 which is header then to overcome it I had tried using:

```
if (GvRow.RowIndex !=0) 
{
    Label test= (Label)GvRow.FindControl("test");
}
```

But it stop at 299 only, not read the 300 row.

Comment: The rowIndex is an array. And like any other it starts at `0`. Your error in thinking is that the header row counts as a normal row, which is not the case. It does not show up in the Rows collection.

Comment: please suggest what we can do to resolve it

Comment: Just start at `0`, so remove `GvRow.RowIndex !=0`

Comment: i did that but at 0 its treat gridview header as row because of which it runs to 299 only

Comment: Can you show how you are adding a second header row to the GridView?

Answer (score 0):

There are 300 records and two headers from which one header is a `GridView` header and another header is treated as a record.

So, there will be assumed 301 rows in `GridView`. Now, you have to *iterate* rows from 301 rows not the 300.